# 'Beneficial' as 'useful' or as 'advantageous'

Tags: word-usage, word-request

In my mother tongue I have ['beneficial'](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=beneficial) word like in English and I would like to use in context of 'useful', but after writing a paragraph, I think I was misunderstood and the receiver thought I used it in the way of 'advantageous'.

My paragraph is:

> It would be **beneficial** for me to know if I will have to do Unit Testing for the technical test.

I just wanted to mannerly ask for *useful* information and make a question like I was allowed to do, but his answer is what makes me think he misunderstood in a bad way (when mentioning 'fair' or the set phrase in bold)

> ... the paragraph of information ... is deliberately vague.
>
> Having said that, **we are not in the business of setting people up to fail**. ... . As a result, our assessment of your completed test will be **fair**.

1. What exactly does the sentence in bold mean?
2. Has the 'beneficial' word a bad connotation in this context, like if I wanted to cheat?
3. Is the word ambiguous or I had just to use 'useful' instead?

Comment: Should I open another post for his answer or just edit? It is like a set phrase, maybe it is me who misunderstood his answer.

Comment: I would recommend just editing. The answer he gave is part of the context, and will help us to understand how he misinterpreted your sentence.

Comment: You should include what the receiver said in reply if possible by [edit]ing this post.

Comment: In a very basic sense, this is like asking what questions will be on the test before it is taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the definitions of [beneficial](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/beneficial):

> 1. producing benefits; advantageous; favorable
> 2. receiving benefit

using *beneficial* makes it seem like you are asking for information for your own advantage or to personally assist you.
In order for their evaluation to be *fair*, they would not be able to provide additional information to only one applicant.

Adding the phrase "Having said that, we are not in the business of setting people up to fail." indicates that the purpose of the *vague* information is not directed at you, and not meant to be unfair. Most likely it allows for a better judgment of someone's skills and creativity.

Using another word like *useful* would not help in this situation, as any personal request for additional information would get the same response.

Comment: Thank you @user3169, should I apologize for my message? and say I meant 'useful'?

Comment: Please check my last edit.

Comment: How you handle any reply at this point is more of a business matter, not a language one.

Comment: But he firstly told me to ask for questions if any. Literally 
> "Please let me know if you have any questions.".
Then I thought it was fair, I didn't ask for the entire test.

Comment: Then I think their answer was appropriate. I don't think an apology is needed or helpful.

Comment: I kind of understand your point. Thank you. Still I think I did not a bad request, at least not for a bad reason of having advantage, but of having an useful scheme to prepare. For me is like asking a teacher if you have to study the 'last lessons' or the 'whole' book. Is fair in my opinion. Not to require for an specific question of course. Cheers.

Comment: @enes You might want to look on [workplace.se] and see if there has been some advice given about this sort of situation. I don't think this is so much of a language or politeness issue as a difference in expectations.